# emailVerification = false in parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

Hi I am trying to use the Parse Api's database for my project which requires user accounts that Parse provides.  While I was reading the tutorial on how to set up user accounts at 
https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#users it stated:

"Enabling email verification in an application's settings allows the application to reserve part of its experience for users with confirmed email addresses. Email verification adds the emailVerified key to the ParseUser object. When a ParseUser's email is set or modified, emailVerified is set to false. Parse then emails the user a link which will set emailVerified to true."

How exactly would you add the emailVerification key = true whenever a user tries to register:

```
ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
user.setUsername(username);
user.setPassword(password);
user.setEmail(email);

user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            // sign up succeeded so go to multiplayer screen
            // store the username of the current player
            currentUser = username;
            final String title = "Account Created Successfully!";
            final String message = "Please verify your email before playing";
            buildAlertDialog(title, message, true);
        } else {
            // sign up didnt succed. //TODO: figure out how do deal with error
            final String title = "Error Account Creation failed";
            final String message = "Account could not be created";
            buildAlertDialog(title, message, false);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The code I have now does not set emailVerified to false. it is just empty now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to your parse.com dashboard, go to settings, email settings and switch on the Verify user emails.

[image]

No code required.

Comment: Thank you for the response! it works! I was just wondering if you knew how to access this field. I would like to do something like if (emailVerified)

Comment: I think using the android API it would be like     boolean emailVerified = user.getBoolean("emailVerified");